# Unity3D - Why is Input.GetButtonDown() firing twice in my code?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make dialog popups, and would like to use the same button to interact with the NPC and then dismiss the menu when the player is done reading.  Currently, my text panel appears and disappears instantaneously.  Here's the code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NPC : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject TextPanel;
    private bool isInteractable = false;


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Accept") && isInteractable)
        {
            NPCInteraction();
            Debug.Log("Button Press 1");
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerStay()
    {
        isInteractable = true;
    }

    void OnTriggerExit()
    {
        isInteractable = false;
    }

    void NPCInteraction()
    {
        TextPanel.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = "This is the dialog from this NPC";
        TextPanel.SetActive(true);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Accept"))
        {
            TextPanel.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Button Press 2");
        }   

    }
}
```

Log shows both button presses when I press the "Accept" button once.  How can I fix the input so it only registers once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your initial button check in `Update()`, you're calling `NPCInteraction()` which does a second button check.

`Input.GetButtonDown()` checks to see what state the input controls are in for the current frame; Those values don't change until the next frame. So because you're still in the same frame, both checks are true and both logs are printed.